# Is it unethical to cheat at solitaire?

Tags: ethics, practical-ethics

When I play solitaire by myself (physical cards), I often cheat.   That is, I get to the point where I would be stuck and I don't end the game.   Instead, I move a card in a manner inconsistent with the rules.

On the one hand, I don't feel bad:

- I do it because I enjoy finishing each game.
- In some sense, I am making up a new solitaire game with a new set of rules.
- Nobody is getting hurt.
- Nobody knows but me.
- Nobody is keeping score.

On the other hand:

- I wouldn't do it if somebody that knows how to play were watching.
- I wouldn't teach my kids to play that way.
- I wouldn't want my mother to know that I do it.
- I end up winning for "real" less because I take longer finishing off the bad games.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. The question "is it unethical" is only appropriate/on topic here when placed in the context of one or two ethical movements. Could you [edit] your question to narrow it down in that way? As it stands now, this question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: I don't know what an ethical movement is.   Can you elaborate?

Comment: [This](http://plato.stanford.edu/search/searcher.py?query=ethics) could be a starting point.

Comment: I think as long as it is not clear wether you think of ethics in the sense of "good=happiness" or "good=morally good", this is not answerable ;)

Comment: ethics according to who?

Comment: In the end you would only be cheating yourself.

Comment: Would cheating at solitaire not always end in a draw?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very amusing question, and I like the considerations you articulate.

To place it in a less solitary context, you are asking about moral standards that are *not* "utilitarian" or "consequentialist." In other words, approaches to morality that are *not* based on harm to others or the consequences of actions.These are sometimes called "deontic."

So your habit of sneaking around behind your own back is wrong only through a "deontic" approach to morality... of which Kant is the best-known "modern" representative. The "wrong" lies in the rational contradiction between the "universalization" of the act and the very assumptions that make the act possible...in this case the rules of solitaire.

Kant's example of lying is similar. If we "universalize" that act, the act of lying itself would not be possible or rational, since it depends in itself on the reliability of language. Ditto for solitaire. In fact, your example plays into the transition from Kant to Wittgenstein, for whom our practices are enabled by their rules or "language games."

Your sense that you wouldn't want your "mother" to know is a good Kantian example of the way "universalizing" such idealism is also grounded in our human social being and "common sense." I believe your question has a funny stance that also invites more nuanced answers. But I'll leave it at this.

I tend to admire Kant. But personally, I cheat at computer chess, by taking back moves. (On the other hand, my chess application cheats too. It often crashes just when I have a nice position set up.)

Comment: Your chess example sheds some light on another reason that I am uncomfortable with it:  cheating may prevent you from becoming more skilled with the real rules.   Granted that solitaire doesn't have as much skill as chess, but it has some skill.  One might hope to become better with practice.